# Pointwise convergence in a special case

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Given continuous functions $f_n,f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ functions such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on compacts and $ (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R} $ a sequence of points.

1. If $(x_n)_n$ is bounded,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|=0.$$
2. If $(x_n)_n$ is unbounded, the existence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|$ cannot be deduced without further assumptions on $(f_n)_n,f$.

Proof:

1. Since $(x_n)_n$ is bounded, there exists a $K>0$ s.t. $x_n\in[-K,K]$ for all $n$. Hence, by using uniform convergence on $[-K,K],$
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{y\in [-K,K]}|f_n(y)-f(y)|=0
   $$
2. Consider the sequence $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-n,n].$ Clearly, $f_n\to0$ uniformly on compacts. However, if $x_n=2n,$ the behaviour of $(f_n(x_n))_n$ is not clear.

Comment: What have you tried?  It may help to note, as just one example of the kind of thing you might begin to investigate, that if $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [-n, n]$, then $f_n$ will converge to $0$ uniformly on compact sets, although the behavior of $f_n(x)$ outside of $[-n,n]$ is (outside of the assumed continuity) otherwise entirely arbitrary

Comment: First, I proved under the assumption that $(x_n)_n$ is convergent that the limit in question exists. In particular, there exists a compact set $K$ s.t. $x_n\in K$ for all $n$ large enough. Thus,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{y\in K}|f_n(y)-f(x)|=0$$

Comment: That's a great start (and wouldn't that same argument work for *any* bounded sequence $(x_n)$, whether or not assumed convergent?).  It might help to add that argument as context to the original question, which at moment is very open-ended.  (I've hinted above that when $(x_n)$ is unbounded the sequence $|f_n(x_n)  - f(x_n)|$ could, consistent with the hypotheses on $(f_n)$ and $f$, potentially be any nonnegative sequence whatsoever. Formalizing this suspicion into a theorem would be one way of providing a "complete" answer to the question (feel free to answer your own question!).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot conclude on the convergence of that limit.

Here are two examples :

$f_n : x \mapsto \frac{x}{n}$ which is obviously uniformly convergent on compacts and its limit is the null function $f$.

Consider $x_n = n^2 $ and $y_n = n$, then limit with the first sequence :
$\lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| = \lim_{n \to \infty} n = + \infty$

However, the limit with the second sequence is $1$ :

$\lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(y_n)-f(y_n)| = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 1$

I hope that helps.